# UICollectionView in a UICollectionViewCell recognizer

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm making a UICollectionView inside a UICollectionViewCell.
So far, so good. But when I try to scroll the smaller one, sometimes it moves the big one, I would like to control this behavior so the one in the top is always the one recognized
Any way to manage that?
Thanks!

Comment: Handle at a time enable scroll for one collection view.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: subclass `UICollectionView` and override `hitTest`:

```
-(UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
   UIView *view = [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];
   self.scrollEnabled = ![view isKindOfClass:[UICollectionView class]];
   return view;
}
```

Then set your root collection view's class to that custom class.

Comment: It didn't work for me. After I reach the edges, it's confusing and next scroll is done in the root UICollectionView